# jSoup get link of each element in table

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to get the link to every team in the table on http://www.statto.com/football/stats/england/premier-league. Currently my code only gets the team names, but seems to output every team as one string... I would like each element to be output as the link, so "Chelsea" would be "http://www.statto.com/football/teams/chelsea".

My current code:

```
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(
            "http://www.statto.com/football/stats/england/premier-league").get();

    Element tableHeader = doc.select("table[class=tabBG]").first();
    for (Element element : tableHeader.children()) {
        // Here you can do something with each element
            String team = element.select("td:eq(1) a").text();
            System.out.println(team);

        }
    }
```

Does anybody know how I can get the link to each item in the table to output as individual strings?

Thanks,

Rob

Answer (score 0):

I have now worked out a solution to my problem, below is the code that works:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(
            "http://www.statto.com/football/stats/germany/bundesliga").get();

    Element tableHeader = doc.select("tbody").first();
    for (Element element : tableHeader.children()) {
        // Here you can do something with each element
        if (element.select("td:eq(1)").html().contains("acronym") != false || element.select("td:eq(1)").html().contains("nbsp") != false){
            //do nothing
        } else {
            String teamname = element.select("td:eq(1) a").html();
            String team = element.select("td:eq(1)").toString()
                    .replace("<a href=\"", "http://www.statto.com").replace(" class=\"b\">", "").replace(teamname, "").replace("<td class=\"steam\">", "").replace("\"</a></td>", "");


            System.out.println(team);

        }

    }
```

Which gives me the below output:

```
http://www.statto.com/football/teams/bayern-munich
http://www.statto.com/football/teams/vfl-wolfsburg
http://www.statto.com/football/teams/borussia-monchengladbach
http://www.statto.com/football/teams/hannover-96
http://www.statto.com/football/teams/tsg-hoffenheim
http://www.statto.com/football/teams/bayer-leverkusen
http://www.statto.com/football/teams/augsburg
http://www.statto.com/football/teams/mainz
http://www.statto.com/football/teams/paderborn-07
http://www.statto.com/football/teams/fc-cologne
http://www.statto.com/football/teams/schalke-04
http://www.statto.com/football/teams/eintracht-frankfurt
http://www.statto.com/football/teams/sc-freiburg
http://www.statto.com/football/teams/hertha-bsc-berlin
http://www.statto.com/football/teams/werder-bremen
http://www.statto.com/football/teams/sv-hamburg
http://www.statto.com/football/teams/vfb-stuttgart
http://www.statto.com/football/teams/borussia-dortmund
```